# Constraints not updating with device orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a [color slider](https://github.com/gizmosachin/ColorSlider) in a tableView cell that extends from the label to the trailingAnchor of the cell. The issue I am having is when the device orientation changes the color slider does not update its constraints and no longer extends the full length of the cell. Below is my code to set up the constraints on the color slider. Below are images to show the issue I am having. If my phone is already in landscape orientation when I present this scene the color slider extends the full length of the cell as desired. However, if I switch to landscape when already viewing this scene the slider appears as below. Here is the [full code](https://github.com/Marcoc88/TimestampApp) if that helps.

[image: Slider Portrait]
[image: Slider Landscape]

```
  func configureColorSlider() {
    let colorSlider = ColorSlider()
    let xCell = colorCell.contentView.bounds.width
    let yCell = colorCell.contentView.bounds.height
    colorSlider.frame = CGRect(x: xCell / 4, y: yCell / 4, width: 200, height: 24)
    colorSlider.orientation = .horizontal
    colorSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ConfigureTimestampTableViewController.changedColor(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    colorCell.contentView.addSubview(colorSlider)

    colorSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([colorSlider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
                                 colorSlider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorCell.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
                                 colorSlider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorCell.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
                                 colorSlider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorCell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8) ])


  }
```

Comment: Is the content of `ColorSlider` using `CALayers`? They don't update their size/position with auto layout.

Comment: It does. Uses CAGradientLayer()  to draw the color slider. That must be the issue. Do you have a recommendation for resizing the slider if I can't use auto layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CALayers` will not be resized in response to their parent `UIView` being resized, whether by auto layout or manually.

You just need to add code to your `ColorSlider` that updates the layer when the size/position of the `ColorSilider` changes. Luckily, there is a method on `UIView` that is specifically for this.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Xcode made me add public to this function when I added it but it worked! Without public it gave me the message "Overriding instance method must be as accessible as its enclosing type"

Comment: Thats correct. If `ColorSlider` is public, any methods you override must be public as well.